# Archive filtering

Tags: categories, archives

I was wondering if I can filter archive posts that are in a specific category, then apply another filter. For example, I have a featured category (where I display featured posts) and then I have my usual categories (like Personal, Blog, Fun).
If i`m on /category/fun can I display all my posts from Fun category that are also in featured?
I tried something, but this kinda shows me all posts from both categories...

```
<?php global $cat;
        $curr_cat = get_category( $cat );
        $cat_name = ( $curr_cat ) ? $curr_cat->cat_name : 'No Category Found!!';
        ?>
        <?php
        $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=featured,'.$cat_name.'&showposts=8');
        while...
?>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `tax_query` argument to `WP_Query`, if I am reading your question correctly.

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array($featured_ID,$curr_cat->cat_ID),
                    'operator' => 'AND'
        )
         )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' =>8
    )
);
```

Untested, but I think that should be close.

Also, where does `global $cat;` come from? I don't remember seeing that as a Core global but maybe I'm wrong. If that isn't set your code will produce a very broken argument:

```
'category_name=featured,No Category Found!!&showposts=8'
```

That may be some of the problem you are seeing.